# File viewer for iOS

Tags: ios, file, viewer, uidocumentinteraction

In my iOS app I need a file viewer that can read all common file formats such as: png, jpg, iWork files, MS Office files. Now I am using standard UIDocumentInteractionController and it's good except some points:

- no ability to hide "Open in" function
- no fullscreen mode in iPhone. On iPad top bar hides by single touch but on iPhone it doesn't
- no ability to zoom more then 100% scale. It is not really usable for text files with small font

Please advice some open source or paid file viewers that meet that requirements.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking for a list of applications, suggest [Apple StackExchange](http://http://apple.stackexchange.com/). There doesn't seem to be a programming question here.

Comment: Not that. I am asking about component or library for file viewing to embed into my app. I described why standard UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't cover my needs.

Answer (score 0):

QLPreviewController, is that what you are looking for?

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html